# Create webpack plugin or loader to inject CSS file

Tags: webpack, extract-text-plugin, webpack-plugin

I am writing a library with which you can render a React application as a web component. Like so:

```
ReactWebComponent.create(<App />, 'my-react-web-component', { css: 'inject' });
```

You can see there is an option `{ css: 'inject' }`. To create a web component with CSS I need to add `<link>` tags to the shadow dom. This happens inside my library.

*Dummy Code:*

```
ReactWebComponent.create = function(options) {
  const proto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype, {
    attachedCallback: {
      value: function() {
        const mountPoint = document.createElement('span');
        const shadowRoot = this.createShadowRoot();
        shadowRoot.appendChild(mountPoint);
        shadowRoot.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', options.css);
        ReactDOM.render(<App />, mountPoint);
      }
    }
  });
  document.registerElement('react-web-component', {prototype: proto});
};
```

Now of course I do not want to append the string `'inject'`. Instead I want to write a Webpack `plugin` or `loader` that takes the CSS files generated by [extract-text-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin) and injects the corresponding `<link>` tags where there is `'inject'`. So from

```
ReactWebComponent.create(<App />, 'my-react-web-component', { css: 'inject' });
```

I want to generate this

```
ReactWebComponent.create(<App />, 'my-react-web-component', { css: '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.a4e5f9.css">' });
```

I think the replacement part can easily be done with `RegEx`, but I am troubled with how to get the CSS file name and how to transform the JS file.